# Invalid trace folder when profiling in Jax

Tags: python, jax

I'm trying to test out the Jax profiler by running the example provided in the docs:

```
import jax 

with jax.profiler.trace("/tmp/jax-trace", create_perfetto_link=True):
  # Run the operations to be profiled
  key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
  x = jax.random.normal(key, (5000, 5000))
  y = x @ x
  y.block_until_ready()
```

However, I repeatedly get `ValueError: Invalid trace folder: /tmp/jax-trace/plugins/profile/{timestamp}`. Based off of the source (https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/jax/_src/profiler.html), this seems to imply that there is no trace dump, but I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue on this problem in [github](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/13009). It seems that TensorFlow profiler is no longer dumping the trace.json file.

Comment: Thank you! I'll track this then.